# Using PDO to run queries and perform numerous actions based on conditions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to refactor a script and put PDO into place, but I'm not incredibly familiar with it.

I've gotten some rather simple queries going with it but I'm trying to establish my basic SELECT queries at the top and then use loops and conditions to perform numerous actions based on the selected values. My problem right now is deleting records based on 2 conditions.

My select returns the correct records and if I echo what records meet the conditions, they print out. But when I run this portion of my script it deletes all records from the table, not just the ones affected by the conditions:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

//PDO statement to select from order_status
$ordStatSql = 'SELECT order_id, order_status, is_placement, date_updated 
                FROM order_status';
try{
$ordStat = $MysqlConn->prepare($ordStatSql);
$result = $ordStat->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
}

while($row = $ordStat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        if(strtotime($row['date_updated']) > strtotime('-5 day')  && $row['is_placement'] == 1){

            $deleteOld = 'DELETE FROM Order_status';
            try{
            $delete = $MysqlConn->prepare($deleteOld);
            $result = $delete->execute();
            $count = $delete->rowcount();
            echo "Records Deleted: " . $count;
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex)
            {
                echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
            }

        }
    }
```

Basically, if one of the rows from the SELECT has is_placement set to 1 and date_updated is more than 5 days old, I want to delete only that record.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're running

```
DELETE FROM Order_status
```

with every row that matches your conditions. That query will simply delete everything in `order_status`, which is what you're experiencing. The immediate solution would be to delete the row with the `order_id` of the current row in the loop:

```
$deleteOld = 'DELETE FROM Order_status WHERE order_id = ?';
try {
    $delete = $MysqlConn->prepare($deleteOld);
    $result = $delete->execute([
        $row["order_id"],
    ]);
    // snip
```

Notice the use of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

However, in order to avoid the [N+1 problem](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/), you should just do *one* query, with the conditions inside it. For example, and if I understood the conditions correctly, such query would look like this:

```
DELETE FROM order_status WHERE is_placement = 1 AND date_updated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Then, you only have to execute one query (not even the `SELECT` is needed).

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and that did work. Thank you! This leads to my other question regarding using PDO to select from one database, store those values in an array and then select from another database using the previous ID as a variable to compare data. This helps to clear up the structure a bit but that has to be another question for me to submit